# Different delete message for community removed posts

Tags: discussion, reputation

Today when I logged in to StackOverflow I saw that there are some reputation lose in my account.

[image: Reputation lose]

I checked and found that two of my answers were removed along with the questions.
But the issue I found is with the delete message.

[image: Delete 1]
[image: Delete 2]

Both messages are different, why that happened ?

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195007/ios-cretion-of-scrollviw-inside-a-uitableview-cell/13195076#13195076)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359256/in-app-purchase-is-getting-rejected/16359395#16359395)

**Another question:**
    I accidentally pressed the `undelete` option in one of my answer, how can I remove my `undelete` vote ?

Comment: The second one is a bug, it shouldn't show the "by owner".

Comment: As for your undelete vote, you can't undo that. Just let it be. It does no harm.